# Define string with the characters *, single quote and $

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, quoting, special-characters

I create bash scripts which get sourced from another "main" script to set up variables needed by the main script. These variables need to be able to contain *any* character and not have them interpreted by the shell. For example:

- a single quote: '
- dollar sign: $
- asterix: *
- pound sign: #, etc.

So, my thinking was to use a single quote and escape any enclosed single quotes and `#` characters. But, am getting a `unexpected EOF while looking for matching` error with the two files below.

### Question:

1. What is the best way to define a string which can contain any set of characters that would require the least amount of tweaking?

   There are thousands of such `foo.sh` files and as the string is being extracted form another source, I want to minimize the number of special characters that I need to escape.
2. What other characters do I need to escape.

The desired output form the following scripts below is

```
\MyMacro{*,Baker's Dozen,$x^$,#}
```

### Platform:

- MacOS 10.9.5

### Sub Shell: foo.sh

```
set -f
string_list='*,Baker\'s Dozen,$x^$,\#'
set +f
```

### Main Shell: main.sh

```
source foo.sh
printf "%s{%s}" "\MyMacro" "${string_list}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to escape `#` inside quote, and it's weird to have literal single quote inside single quote:

```
string_list='*,Baker'\''s Dozen,$x^$,#'
```

But it's easier with double quotes. So something like:

```
string_list="*,Baker's Dozen,\$x^\$,#"
```

will work.

You only need `"\""` for double quote, instead of `''\'''` for single quote, and also escaping `$` to prevent variable expansion.

If you want to minimize the escaping, then change any `'` inside single quote to `'"'"'`:

```
string_list='*,Baker'"'"'s Dozen,$x^$,#'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid any escaping, but with a bit more overhead, by using something like this:

```
string_list=$(cat <<\!eof!
*,Baker's Dozen,$x^$,#
!eof!
)
```

where you cat stdin which is a here-is document that will have no processing done to it. You can even have backslashes, single and double quotes, whitespace and multiple lines in the string.  To be a bit more efficient you can use this:

```
read string_list <<\!eof!
*,Baker's Dozen,$x^$,#
!eof!
```

but you will lose any initial whitespace and any backslashes.

Comment: Since one of the requirements is to be able to store any character, it should be noted that the command substitution approach cannot handle a single newline or trailing newlines. read strips the delimiter, so it cannot appear in the string.